# How can I extend a lexical cast to support enumerated types?

Tags: c++, serialization, enums, casting, lexical-cast

I have the following function that will convert a string into a numeric data type:

```
template <typename T>
bool ConvertString(const std::string& theString, T& theResult)
{
    std::istringstream iss(theString);
    return !(iss >> theResult).fail();
}
```

This does not work for enumerated types, however, so I have done something like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool ConvertStringToEnum(const std::string& theString, T& theResult)
{
    std::istringstream iss(theString);
    unsigned int temp;
    const bool isValid = !(iss >> temp).fail();
    theResult = static_cast<T>(temp);
    return isValid;
}
```

(I'm making the assumption that theString has a valid value for the enumerated type; I'm using this mainly for simple serialization)

Is there a way to create a single function that combines both of these?

I've played a bit with the template arguments but haven't come up with anything; it'd just be nice not to have to call one function for enumerated types and another for everything else.

Thank you

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have to do two steps. Finding an integral type large enough to store the values. You could use `unsigned long`, but the values could be negative. Then you could use `long` but the values could extend into the range of `unsigned long`. So there is not really a fit-it-all type.

There is a trick though, by using overload resolution. Here is it

```
template<typename T>
struct id { typedef T type; };

id<char[1]>::type &find_etype(int);
id<char[2]>::type &find_etype(unsigned int);
id<char[3]>::type &find_etype(long);
id<char[4]>::type &find_etype(unsigned long);
```

You can change it appropriately to cover also `long long` or `unsigned long long` if your implementation has support for that. Now, passing an enum type will prefer one of these over all the other ones - that's a type that can store all values of it. You just need to pass `sizeof` of the return type to some template.

```
template<int> struct get_etype;
template<> struct get_etype<1> { typedef int type; };
template<> struct get_etype<2> { typedef unsigned int type; };
template<> struct get_etype<3> { typedef long type; };
template<> struct get_etype<4> { typedef unsigned long type; };
```

Now, you can get a right type. All you need now is to see whether some type is an enumeration. How to do this is described in the book "C++ Templates - The complete Guide", and unfortunately is a whole lot of code. So i would use boost's [`is_enum`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_enum.html). Putting it together, it could look like

```
template <typename T>
typename boost::disable_if< boost::is_enum<T>, bool>::type 
ConvertString(const std::string& theString, T& theResult)
{
    std::istringstream iss(theString);
    return !(iss >> theResult).fail();
}

template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_enum<T>, bool>::type 
ConvertString(const std::string& theString, T& theResult)
{
    typedef typename get_etype<sizeof find_etype(theResult)>::type 
      safe_type;

    std::istringstream iss(theString);
    safe_type temp;
    const bool isValid = !(iss >> temp).fail();
    theResult = static_cast<T>(temp);
    return isValid;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. I was also about to write a comment about why this was not in the standard library, until I read GMan's answer below.

Comment: boost is not needed anymore as std::enable_if and std::is_enum provide these functionalities in C++11

Answer (score 10):

And just to "complete" the question, in C++0x we can just do this:

```
typedef typename std::underlying_type<T>::type safe_type;
```

In place of Johannes `get_etype` trick.

Comment: Awesome; what a convenient feature.  I was such a noob when I asked this question... I mean, I'm still a noob, but I was much more a noob then.