# Template specialization for enum

Tags: c++, templates, enums, template-specialization

Is it possible to specialize a templatized method for enums?

Something like (the invalid code below):

```
template <typename T>
void f(T value);

template <>
void f<enum T>(T value);
```

In the case it's not possible, then supposing I have specializations for a number of types, like `int`, `unsigned int`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`, etc, then which of the specializations an enum value will use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762892/how-to-specialize-a-template-function-for-enum-and-specific-type

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) with [`std::is_enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum) from `<type_traits>` to accomplish this.

[In an answer to one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528374/how-can-i-extend-a-lexical-cast-to-support-enumerated-types/1528436#1528436), litb posted a *very* detailed and well-written explanation of how this can be done with the Boost equivalents.

Comment: This looks like it might work. I'm taking a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can instantiate the template on specific enums:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T value);

enum cars { ford, volvo, saab, subaru, toyota };
enum colors { red, black, green, blue };

template <>
void f<cars>(cars) { }

template <>
void f<colors>(colors) { }

int main() {
    f(ford);
    f(red);
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because I don't have the enum type beforehand.

Comment: in C++11 you have the type and hence you can create the enum template. A nicer topic would be to create a template based on a particular values of the enum (f<ford>). still possible with some tricker or can be avoided by just declaring classes instead of enum values.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the only interesting thing you could do with a type that they only thing you know about it is that it's an enum, is cast it to its underlying type and operate on that. Here's how that might look like, using James' suggested approach (AKA [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)):

```
void Bar(int b); // and/or other underlying types

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, void>::type
Foo(T enm)
{
    Bar(static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>(enm));
}
```

As a related bonus, here's a similar method that would only get resolved for a specific type of your choosing (replace bool in `is_same` to the type of your choosing):

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,bool>::value, void>::type
Baz(T bl)
{
    if (bl)
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `std::enable_if` in one of the template arguments.
If it cannot compile, the function is not instantiated at all (SFINAE).

```cpp
template <typename T>
void f(T value) 
{ /* implementation A */ }

template <typename T,
          typename = std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, bool>::type >
void f(T value) 
{ /* implementation B */ }
```

I am proposing the above solution as a complement to the ones suggesting that you use `std::enable_if` as the return type if your function. In your question, you did not wish to change the return type.