# Why is boost::call_traits<T>::param_type a reference for enumerated types?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

A basic C++ 03 enumerated type is just an integral value with a fancy name, therefore I would expect to pass it by value....

For this reason I would also expect `boost::call_traits<T>::param_type` with `T=SomeEnum` to determine that the most efficient way of pass `T` is by value.

From boost documentation see [Call Traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm):

> Defines a type that represents the "best" way to pass a parameter of type T to a function.

When I use `boost::call_traits<T>::param_type` with `T=SomeEnum` it determines that SomeEnum should be passed by reference.

I would also  expect `C++11 class enums` to also be passed by value.

Test Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/call_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp>

enum SomeEnum
{
    EN1_ZERO = 0,
    EN1_ONE,
    EN1_TWO,
    EN1_THREE
};

struct SomeStruct
{};

template<typename T>
void DisplayCallTraits( const std::string& desc )
{
    typedef typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type param_type;
    std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Call traits for: " << desc << "\n";
    std::cout << "\ttypeof T : " << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << "\ttypeof param_type : " << typeid(param_type).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << "\tis_reference<param_type> : " << std::boolalpha 
              << boost::is_reference<param_type>::value << "\n";
}

int main( int, char** )
{
    DisplayCallTraits< unsigned >( "unsigned" );     // pass by value, as expected
    DisplayCallTraits< SomeStruct >( "struct" );     // pass by reference, as expected
    DisplayCallTraits< SomeEnum >( "enumeration" );  // pass by reference - why?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had a little look through the [code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/detail/call_traits.hpp), and came to the conclusion that it depends on [`is_integral`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp), which is false for enums. It is specialised for all integral types to be true, and false for everything else. I never really thought about it before, but I guess `enum`s can't be `int`s in templates, even though they can in function arguments.

Comment: Heh, apparently this could be done with boost [`is_enum`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_enum.html) if they wanted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619993/template-specialization-for-enum
So maybe it was a deliberate choice? Or just overlooked?

Comment: @BoBTFish the `enum`/`int` in templates is something that had tripped me up, prompting this question....  anyway I would still expect `boost::call_traits` to determine that an `enum` should be passed by value, `boost::call_traits` could always use `boost::is_enum` as well as `is_integral`.

Comment: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5790

Comment: @BoBTFish I guess it must be fixed in the latest release (1.52) I'll check on Monday. Could you put the link to the ticket in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been updated to include a check to `is_enum` in the implementation. See this bug report, closed 2 months ago: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5790