# C++ specialise function on enum

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums, specialization

Is it possible to specialise a template function on an `enum`?

I've seen noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619993/template-specialization-for-enum) a template function can be disabled if it isn't an enum, but is this possible whilst still allowing other types?

My example below shows specialisations for `int`, `float`, and `enum` (it doesn't compile because it tries to overload the `enum` version rather than specialising it). I feel I'm missing something obvious.

Note that I'm looking to specialise on *any* enum, not just a named one (`EAnEnum` in the example)

```
#include <iostream>

enum class EAnEnum
{
    Alpha,
    Beta,
};

template<typename T>
void MyFunc();

template<>
void MyFunc<int>()
{
    std::cout << "Int" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void MyFunc<float>()
{
    std::cout << "Float" << std::endl;
}

// MyFunc<Enum>
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, void>::type MyFunc()
{
    std::cout << "Enum" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    MyFunc<EAnEnum>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to perform a partial specialization of a function template. There ain't no such thing - you can do full specialization, or overloading. One possible approach - put your enum-specific implementation into a primary template, perhaps with a `static_assert` that the type is in fact an enum.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve. No, not this question, but the problem to which you think the answer is this kind of a specialization.

Comment: In general function specialization fails to be the best way to solve almost every problem that you try to solve with it.  In short, there is going to be a better way.  Solutions end up brittle and awkward.  Describe real problem, solve it another way.

Comment: I'm using the `>>` operator on a stream, I want to specialise it to read enums differently from ints in the file without having to break out from the `my_stream >> x >> y >> z;` pattern, as a `ReadInt()`, `ReadEnum()` pattern would require. I don't know the types of the enums in advance. I agree there is probably a better solution but the question still stands as a thought exercise :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot partially specialize a function, but you can use *tag dispatching* instead.
It follows a minimal, working example based on the OP's question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<type_traits>

enum class EAnEnum
{
    Alpha,
    Beta,
};

template<typename>
struct tag {};

void MyFunc(tag<int>)
{
    std::cout << "Int" << std::endl;
}

void MyFunc(tag<float>)
{
    std::cout << "Float" << std::endl;
}

void MyFunc(tag<EAnEnum>)
{
    std::cout << "Enum" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void MyFunc() {
    MyFunc(tag<std::decay_t<T>>{});
}

int main()
{
    MyFunc<EAnEnum>();
    return 0;
}
```

You can easily add a parameter pack to be forwarded to the *right* `MyFunc` and still use this technique to solve your problem.
Of course, you can now specialize for any enum.
You can also provide a fallback `MyFunc` as:

```
template<typename T>
void MyFunc(tag<T>)
{
    std::cout << "Fallback" << std::endl;
}
```

If you want a fallback for all the possible enum types, you can now rely on SFINAE, for these are different overloaded functions:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value>
MyFunc(tag<T>)
{
    std::cout << "Fallback for enums only" << std::endl;
}
```

Note that you should not use directly the implications of `MyFunc` that accept a `tag` specialization as an entry point.
Those are meant as *internal* functions.
Use instead the generic one, as shown in the example.

Comment: Doesn't this still leave me with needing to state the name of my enum explicitly, as in `tag<EAnEnum>)`?

Comment: @cz For those are overloaded functions, you can now use _sfinae_ on your `fallbacks` if needed. Let me edit the question to clarify this point.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot partially specialize a function template, but can you just let it forward to a class template.

Since your function doesn't have arguments that's particularly easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace impl {
    using namespace std;

    template< class Type, bool is_enum_ = is_enum<Type>::value >
    struct Foo;

    template< class Type >
    struct Foo<Type, true>
    { void func() { cout << "Enum" << endl; } };

    template<>
    struct Foo<int>
    { void func() { cout << "Int" << endl; } };

    template<>
    struct Foo<float>
    { void func() { cout << "Float" << endl; } };

}  // namespace impl

template< class Type >
void foo()
{ impl::Foo<Type>().func(); }

auto main()
    -> int
{
    enum class An_enum
    {
        alpha, beta,
    };

    foo<An_enum>();
    foo<int>();
    foo<float>();
    #ifdef TEST
        foo<char>();    //! Doesn't compile.
    #endif
}
```

With arguments you can use “perfect forwarding” (which isn't all that perfect, really, but usually good enough) via `std::forward`.