# Using stringstream instead of `sscanf` to parse a fixed-format string

Tags: c++

I would like to use the facilities provided by `stringstream` to extract values from a fixed-format `string` as a type-safe alternative to `sscanf`.  How can I do this?

Consider the following specific use case.  I have a `std::string` in the following fixed format:

`YYYYMMDDHHMMSSmmm`

Where:

```
YYYY = 4 digits representing the year
MM = 2 digits representing the month ('0' padded to 2 characters)
DD = 2 digits representing the day ('0' padded to 2 characters)
HH = 2 digits representing the hour ('0' padded to 2 characters)
MM = 2 digits representing the minute ('0' padded to 2 characters)
SS = 2 digits representing the second ('0' padded to 2 characters)
mmm = 3 digits representing the milliseconds ('0' padded to 3 characters)
```

Previously I was doing something along these lines:

```
string s = "20101220110651184";
unsigned year = 0, month = 0, day = 0, hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, milli = 0;    
sscanf(s.c_str(), "%4u%2u%2u%2u%2u%2u%3u", &year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &milli );
```

The width values are magic numbers, and that's ok.  I'd like to use streams to extract these values and convert them to `unsigned`s in the interest of type safety.  But when I try this:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << "20101220110651184";
ss >> setw(4) >> year;
```

`year` retains the value `0`.  It should be `2010`.

How do I do what I'm trying to do?  I can't use Boost or any other 3rd party library, nor can I use C++0x.

Comment: `setw()` is for writing output. It doesn't work for reading in.

Comment: Maybe you should seek back to the beginning of the stream before extracting the first field.

Comment: @Ben: Or better yet, just `std::stringstream ss("20101220110651184");`

Comment: "I can't use Boost or any other 3rd party library" Why not?

Comment: @Ben, @Billy:  Seeking & initializing had no effect on the result.  @marcog:  This is in fact exactlty my problem.  How do I get the effect I'm seeking with `setw`?

Comment: @Karl:  Irrelevant, but suffuce it to say that it's not part of our tree.

Comment: For the record, it seems I was slightly incorrect: it works for reading in strings and cstrings.

Comment: in c++11 you don't need stringstream for this. substr() and stoi() should do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One not particularly efficient option would be to construct some temporary strings and use a lexical cast:

```
std::string s("20101220110651184");
int year = lexical_cast<int>(s.substr(0, 4));
// etc.
```

`lexical_cast` can be implemented in just a few lines of code; Herb Sutter presented the bare minimum in his article, ["The String Formatters of Manor Farm."](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm)

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it's a type-safe way to extract fixed-width fields from a string.

Comment: I can't use `lexical_cast`, as that's part of Boost.

Comment: Although I could use streams again or some `atoi` type stuff.  I was hoping I could accomplish this in a more natural way, though.

Comment: @John: You can write your own quite easily. I've linked to one of Herb Sutter's articles where a very basic implementation is presented (seven nicely formatted lines of code). Or, I posted a very simple version in [my first Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528374/how-can-i-extend-a-lexical-cast-to-support-enumerated-types); that one is two lines of code.

Answer (score 5):

Erm, if it's fixed format, why don't you do this?

```
  std::string sd("20101220110651184");
  // insert spaces from the back
  sd.insert(14, 1, ' ');
  sd.insert(12, 1, ' ');
  sd.insert(10, 1, ' ');
  sd.insert(8, 1, ' ');
  sd.insert(6, 1, ' ');
  sd.insert(4, 1, ' ');
  int year, month, day, hour, min, sec, ms;
  std::istringstream str(sd);
  str >> year >> month >> day >> hour >> min >> sec >> ms;
```

Comment: You're basically creating a new space-delimited string which the >> operator can parse because it contains spaces... Not very efficient.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following, it might be useful for you:

```
template<typename T> T stringTo( const std::string& s )
   {
      std::istringstream iss(s);
      T x;
      iss >> x;
      return x;
   };

template<typename T> inline std::string toString( const T& x )
   {
      std::ostringstream o;
      o << x;
      return o.str();
   }
```

These templates require:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Usage

```
long date;
date = stringTo<long>( std::cin );
```

YMMV

Comment: In the `stringTo` function, it is very important to check the state of `iss` after the extraction to ensure it succeeded and handle errors appropriately (throw an exception, return an error code, abort the application, whatever).

Comment: +1 this is, at its core, basically what @James suggests above.  I was hoping to use something already provided by the StdLib, but I may have to write it myself

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Programming+Cpp/Chapter+9.+Input+and+Output/9.2+Text+IO/), you might find this useful:

```
template<typename T, typename charT, typename traits>
std::basic_istream<charT, traits>&
  fixedread(std::basic_istream<charT, traits>& in, T& x)
{
  if (in.width(  ) == 0)
    // Not fixed size, so read normally.
    in >> x;
  else {
    std::string field;
    in >> field;
    std::basic_istringstream<charT, traits> stream(field);
    if (! (stream >> x))
      in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
  }
  return in;
}
```

`setw()` only applies to reading in of strings cstrings. The above function use this fact, reading into a string and then casting it to the required type. You can use it in combination with `setw()` or `ss.width(w)` to read in a fixed-width field of any type.

Comment: +1 This, again, is essentially what @James suggested as well.  I'm sensing a trend here... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
struct FixedRead {
    T& content;
    int size;
    FixedRead(T& content, int size) :
            content(content), size(size) {
        assert(size != 0);
    }
    template<typename charT, typename traits>
    friend std::basic_istream<charT, traits>&
    operator >>(std::basic_istream<charT, traits>& in, FixedRead<T> x) {
        int orig_w = in.width();
        std::basic_string<charT, traits> o;
        in >> setw(x.size) >> o;
        std::basic_stringstream<charT, traits> os(o);
        if (!(os >> x.content))
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        in.width(orig_w);
        return in;
    }
};

template<typename T>
FixedRead<T> fixed_read(T& content, int size) {
    return FixedRead<T>(content, size);
}

void test4() {
    stringstream ss("20101220110651184");
    int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0, hour = 0, min = 0, sec = 0, ms = 0;
    ss >> fixed_read(year, 4) >> fixed_read(month, 2) >> fixed_read(day, 2)
            >> fixed_read(hour, 2) >> fixed_read(min, 2) >> fixed_read(sec, 2)
            >> fixed_read(ms, 4);
    cout << "year:" << year << "," << "month:" << month << "," << "day:" << day
            << "," << "hour:" << hour << "," << "min:" << min << "," << "sec:"
            << sec << "," << "ms:" << ms << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of ps5mh is really nice, but does not work for fixed-size parsing of strings that include white spaces. The following solution fixes this:

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
struct FixedRead
{
    T& content;
    T2& number;
    int size;
    FixedRead(T& content, int size, T2 & number) :
        content(content), number(number), size(size)
    {
        assert (size != 0);
    }
    template<typename charT, typename traits>
    friend std::basic_istream<charT, traits>&
    operator >>(std::basic_istream<charT, traits>& in, FixedRead<T,T2> x)
    {
        if (!in.eof() && in.good())
        {
            std::vector<char> buffer(x.size+1);
            in.read(buffer.data(), x.size);
            int num_read = in.gcount();
            buffer[num_read] = 0; // set null-termination of string
            std::basic_stringstream<charT, traits> os(buffer.data());
            if (!(os >> x.content))
                in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
            else
                ++x.number;
        }
        return in;
    }
};
template<typename T, typename T2>
FixedRead<T,T2> fixedread(T& content, int size, T2 & number) {
    return FixedRead<T,T2>(content, size, number);
}
```

This can be used as:

```
std::string s  = "90007127       19000715790007397";
std::vector<int> ints(5);
int num_read = 0;
std::istringstream in(s);
in >> fixedread(ints[0], 8, num_read) 
   >> fixedread(ints[1], 8, num_read) 
   >> fixedread(ints[2], 8, num_read) 
   >> fixedread(ints[3], 8, num_read) 
   >> fixedread(ints[4], 8, num_read);
// output: 
//   num_read = 4 (like return value of sscanf)
//   ints = 90007127, 1, 90007157, 90007397
//   ints[4] is uninitialized
```