# std::cin extract to enum

Tags: c++, enums, stream

I don't understand why I can't to that:

```
enum MyEnum {X=1, Y};
...
X x;
std::cin >> x;
```

the problem is that C++ is not smart enougth or I'm mistaking something?

Comment: `MyEnum` is a user defined type.  How smart do you think the language (compiler) have to be to "guess" in what format you want to output any given user defined types?

Comment: @André: not so much. enum are represented by integer. By the way, I want to do input, not output.

Comment: `class X { int x; }` is also represented by an integer.  It doesn't change the fact that it is a user defined type (UDT). This is also why the compiler does not implicit cast to enum types.  The "input integer + cast to enum" in James' answer is a way to circumvent this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but you need to write a custom `operator>>` overload:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std;:istream& is, MyEnum& e) { ... }
```

The reason you cannot do this with the default `std::istream` `operator>>` overloads is that the right side argument must exactly match the parameter of the operator overload because it is taken by non-const reference (because the operator is going to modify the object by assigning to it).

Another option would be to extract the integer representation from the stream into an `int` and then cast it to the enumeration type:

```
int i;
MyEnum e;

if (!(std::cin >> i)) { /* handle error */ }
e = static_cast<MyEnum>(i);
```

You probably want to perform some error checking here, unless you are certain that the extracted value is able to be represented by `MyEnum`.  (Technically, you should also be careful with extracting to `int`, since `int` may not be able to represent all the values of `MyEnum`.  There's an explanation of how to do this in an answer to another question, [How can I extend a lexical cast to support enumerated types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528374/how-can-i-extend-a-lexical-cast-to-support-enumerated-types))