# function template for serialization of enums

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, enums

I have written a function template for serialization of enums to/from our stream class (Yes, I know boost::serialization, but it is not an option in my situation). Enums by convention in our company are serialized as `int`:

```
template<typename T>
Stream& operator<<( Stream& s, T const& value )
{
    s << ( int ) value;
}

template<typename T>
Stream& operator>>( Stream& s, T & value )
{
    int v;
    s >> v;
    value = (T) v;
}
```

These are simple templates, and they work nicely also in my function templates for (de)serializing a vector of enumeration items. I'm worried though that they are overly generic, i.e. that they get applied also for types `T` that are not `enums` but can be cast to/from an `int`. Can I improve the enum-serialization templates (or maybe the vector-serialization templates) to make sure they only apply to vectors of `enum`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two improvements to be made here: not always serializing as `int` (not all enums are), but as whatever the underlying type is. And, as your request, to only accept enums.

The latter is easily solved with `std::enable_if` and `std::is_enum`:

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, Stream&>::type
    operator<<( Stream& s, T const& value )

// and likewise for operator>>
```

And for the former, do the following inside the function:

```
Stream& operator<<( Stream& s, T const& value )
{
    typedef typename std::underlying_type<T>::type safe_type;
    s << static_cast<safe_type>(value);
}

// and likewise for operator>>
```

This requires C++0x.

If that's not an option, both `enable_if` and `is_enum` can be found within Boost. However, I think you'll [need to make `underlying_type` yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528374/how-can-i-extend-a-lexical-cast-to-support-enumerated-types). (And of course, in the worse case you can do all three yourself, though `is_enum` can be a pain, if I recall correctly.)