# String into Enum c++

Tags: string, enums

i know that this question have been answered here already : [C++ string to enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163069/c-string-to-enum)
 but i'm really lost on how to use it so please don't be rude ;)

I want to convert my string in a tEnumCouleur.. 
I have :

```
    #pragma once
    #include <map>
    #include <cassert>
    class EnumCouleur
    {
    public :

        enum tEnumCouleur{BLACK,BLUE,RED,GREEN,YELLOW,CYAN};
    std::map<std::string, tEnumCouleur> xmap = boost::assign::map_list_of<std::string, tEnumCouleur>(BLACK, "BLACK")(BLUE, "BLUE")(GREEN, "GREEN");

    //Getting an error with the "=" saying it's an unautorized initialisation 
//also getting an error at the end of std::map<std::string, tEnumCouleur> xmap = boost::assign::map_list_of<std::string, tEnumCouleur>, asking for ";" 
        // static car ce get ne sappele pas sur un objet EnumCouleur (il sera toujours le même) cout<<EnumCouleurs::c_Str(v)
        static const char * c_Str(tEnumCouleur l) {
            return strEnumCouleur[l];}
        std::map<std::string, tEnumCouleur> xmap;
    private :
        static char * strEnumCouleur[];
        //EnumCouleur();

    };
```

and a .cpp to allow me to convert enum into string :

```
#include "EnumCouleur.h"
#include <string>

char * EnumCouleur::strEnumCouleur[] = {
    "BLACK","BLUE","RED","GREEN","YELLOW","CYAN"
};
```

i ve tried both things that i found on the topic i linkd :

```
std::map<std::string, tEnumCouleur> xmap = boost::map_list_of("A", A)("B", B)("C",C);

struct responseHeaderMap : public std::map<std::string, tEnumCouleur>
{
    responseHeaderMap()
    {
        this->operator[]("BLACK") =  BLACK;
        this->operator[]("BLUE") = BLUE;
        this->operator[]("RED") = RED;
        this->operator[]("GREEN") =  GREEN;
        this->operator[]("YELLOW") = YELLOW;
        this->operator[]("CYAN") = CYAN;
    };
    ~responseHeaderMap(){}
};
```

I really don't know how to use it.. let's say my program got a string from a textdocument. i'm sure that this string is correct. I want to make as an tEnumCouleur, in way to fit a contructor :

`Segment( const Point p1, const Point p2, EnumCouleur::tEnumCouleur v);`

How do i do that please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ string to enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163069/c-string-to-enum)

Comment: Did you read Captain?

Comment: @Niko It _is_ a duplicate of that question. The fact that you didn't understand the answer doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need to do is flip your `std::map` around so it maps string to `enum` rather than `enum` to string. Then, you can do `xmap[string]` and get your `enum`.

So you can do

```
std::map<std::string, tEnumCouleur> xmap = boost::assign::map_list_of<std::string, tEnumCouleur>(A, "A")(B, "B")(C, "C");
```

and then you can simply do `xmap["BLACK"]` and you'll get the enum value BLACK

Comment: Also, it was a complete coincidence that I happened to open SO at the exact moment that you posted a question based off of my question.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "flip" my map sorry .. , so it's std::map<tEnumCouleur,std::string> = ... but where do i need to put it ?

Comment: " and you'll get the string "BLACK"" , you mean the enum right ? because what i want is the enum!

Comment: i just still don't know where to put the map declaration + value. seems like i can't do it below my enum declaration how to fix that ?

Comment: @Niko You will _have_ to put it below your enum declaration. It is impossible to answer you without providing more details such as error messages.

Comment: @Niko "Check it please" is not a good way to get someone to help you. If you're not going to put any effort into it, why should I?

Comment: well, i m not english native, this sounded polite to me. May you check it sir ? :)