# How to convert a string to map to its respective enum type integer?

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, stdstring, stdarray

I'm trying to create a program that will ask the user to enter an animal name and will print its respective age.

This is what I have so far, I'm using `enum` types and `std::arrays` to map easily it's values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>  
#include <array>


namespace Animal
{
    enum Type
    {
        dog,  //0
        cat,  //1
        snake,  //2
        chicken,  //3
        max_animals, //4
    };


    //defining array of enumerator types “Type” 
    constexpr std::array <Type, max_animals> types {dog, cat, snake, chicken};


    //defining an array of string_view with the animal names
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;
    constexpr std::array <std::string_view, max_animals> names { "dog"sv, "cat"sv, "snake"sv, "chicken"sv }; //names


    //defining an array of integers with animal ages
    std::array age {8, 5, 11, 2}; //array of integers (implicitly deducted)


    static_assert(std::size(types) == max_animals);
    static_assert(std::size(names) == max_animals);
    static_assert(std::size(age) == max_animals);
}


int main()
{

    std::cout << "Enter an animal name to show their age  ";
    int x{};
    std::cin >> x; //i.e x = "snake"



//Conversion from string to its matching enum (i.e "snake" -> 2 integer)
    Animal::Type my_name{};  //initializing an enum type

    my_name = static_cast<Animal::Type>(x); //converting "snake"

    std::cout << my_name;


   //std::cout << "The age for " << Animal::names[ Animal::types[x] ] << " is " << Animal::age [ Animal::types[x] ];


    return 0;
}
```

I'm just a little stuck for hours in how to solve this.
So I need to convert the string that was  inputted into variable `x`, somehow to the appropiate enum number.

So that I can then use this number as an index to the `age` array.

---

EDIT: Develop a C++ program utilizing an unscoped enum type and std::array to facilitate a user input system. The program should prompt the user to enter a name, and based on this input, print the corresponding age.

Comment: Do your exercise require the use of enumerations and arrays? If not, why not simply a map from the animal name to the age? Like `std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned> animal_ages = { { "dog", 8 }, ... };`

Comment: It does unfortunately

Comment: Please include the full and complete assignment/exercise in your question, so we can see the requirements and limitations.

Comment: A hint: use std::map<std::string, Animal::Type> (or even unordered_map). Get the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7163130/5821185)

Comment: As for a possible solution using arrays, find the index in the `names` array. Use that index in the `types` array to get the corresponding enumeration value. This of course requires that the `names` and `types` arrays are synchronized.

Comment: The dumbest option is `std::find`ing the string in `names` (and if you're not allowed to use maps, this might be your only option). Also `types` is a useless array. You can just cast the index to the enum instead of using it.

Comment: You need to include the constraints in the question (edit it), not in comments.  Otherwise pretty much everyone will suggest a `std::map` or variant thereof.  You even said "map" in your question, indicating the more appropriate container.  You simply have to iterate the string list to find a matching string (or use `std::find` to do the same thing) and cast the index to the enum.  That is rather too obvious to warrant the question - make an attempt and see how it goes.

Comment: I updated it with instructions

Comment: This is not an answer to your specific question, but to solve the issue you can ask the user to input a number based on a menu you can display. e.g. For Snake Press: 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `namespace Animal` implementation, I think the easier way to achieve this is to input the animal's name as a string and find the index of that name in the `names` array.
Here is your modified `main` function.

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an animal name to show their age: ";
    std::string x;
    std::cin >> x; //i.e x = "snake"

    // Find the index of the animal's name in the names array
    auto it = std::find(Animal::names.begin(), Animal::names.end(), x);

    // If the animal's name was found in the array
    if (it != Animal::names.end())
    {
        // Get the index of the found animal name
        int index = std::distance(Animal::names.begin(), it);

        // Use the index to get the age of the animal
        std::cout << "The age of the " << Animal::names[index] << " is " << Animal::age[index] << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Animal not found\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```